# How many instances are created when we autowired a class in different controller

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

How many instances are created and injected in this case ?

```
@Component
public class XYZ {

    @Autowired
    Hello hello;

}

@Component
public class XYZ1 {

    @Autowired
    Hello hello1;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the scope of the bean is singleton, then only one single object(bean) is created in IOC container at the startup so that it can be shared throughout the application.

When you are autowiring that class, then the shared object of that class will be injected only and no extra object(bean) is created as you autowire.

So, both `XYZ` and `XYZ1` get the same shared Hello singleton object from IOC Container which is present & created at the startup of the application.